# Compute engine instance move

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, instance, google-compute-engine

I have a wordpress site installed on a compute engine instance.
I would like to move it on a new instance with SSD disk and other region as now it runs on standard persistence disk and Google opened new datacenter in my country.

I have upgrated the Ubuntu server to get HTTP/2 support and installed ssl keys for the https support.

Is there a way to move the existing instance with all configuration to new without needing to do it all again?

I read about the disk snapshots but am not sure if it includes everything from the old instance or is it just partial (missing the server update, ssl keys etc)?

It would be great if you guys could help me out because I am a Google cloud noobie with limited technical knowledge.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to move the compute engine instance to another zone within the same region you can simply just use the [gcloud compute instances move](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/) command in the Google Cloud shell to move it to a different zone.

Quote from the documentation:

> For example, running
>
> ```
> gcloud compute instances move example-instance-1 \
>      --zone us-central1-b --destination-zone us-central1-f
> ```
>
> Will move the instance called example-instance-1 with its all attached
>   persistent disks, currently running in us-central1-b, to
>   us-central1-f.

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/move
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones

Comment: Thank you for the links. I am moving the instance to other region. Tried to do it by the instructions but it did not move the ssl keys etc.

Comment: just to understand what do you mean by moving the ssl key ? the ssl key is related to your FQDN, first try to see if you kept the same external IP, and you DNS record are configured correctly